# Indenting non-code text

Tags: support, markdown

Is it possible to indent text without having it show as code or a list? Basically tabbing without getting a code block.

I can't help but think that I remember seeing this once in a post. Perhaps I'm wrong, but I want to double-check.

The formatting help section doesn't seem to describe such a feature.

Comment: Hmm, an ugly workaround is using `&nbsp;`. It does work in posts.

Comment: @M.A.R., oh yes indeed! Thank you! I was hoping I could indent paragraphs, but this is better than nothing for sure.

Comment: you could also be tricky and use a space a a zero width joiner which acts like a non breaking space

Comment: Why do you **need** to indent this text? We have other options for quotes / spacing etc.

Comment: @Paulie_D Just for formatting purposes. I have a few headers and subheaders. Id like the indentation to clarify the tree-like structure. In long posts it just looks better.

Comment: I'd use the markdown options for heading levels and the horizontal rule option to separate them...or lists...no need to re-invent the wheel or *abuse* the `&nbsp;`

Comment: @Paulie_D, Yeah I am already using hr and various header sizes... lists would be perfect if there was an option to hide the bullets because they'd look *horrible* on a header.

Comment: "_In long posts it just looks better."_ * Citation needed

Comment: @Cerbrus What??

Comment: @Chris: I'd argue that indenting text on Stack Overflow like that isn't a very good-looking solution.

Comment: @Cerbrus noted.

Comment: @danlowe it is not clear from your comment what "this" refers to as two sides of an argument were presented in prior comments...

Answer (score 7):

No. There is no Markdown feature for indenting prose. Please don't abuse HTML to simulate it.

As a factor of *style* rather than *substance*, "I want to indent this bit of text" shouldn't enter your mind when composing your post in Markdown. This is the job of the renderer.

If you feel that a change to how Stack Overflow currently renders Markdown would make certain posts more easy to read, please go ahead and suggest such a change. This could be something like, "sequentially indent paragraphs underneath headings".

Personally, I don't think we need any changes, and have never seen a post on Stack Overflow which would benefit from different [prose] indentation; frankly it sounds like your post is too long for this format. Note that books don't generally use such an indentation scheme either.

Comment: Mind you, if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43892905/560648) is the answer you're referring to, I guess I can see the use case.

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Though I've posted one or two long posts before as well that would benefit if you ask me.

Comment: @Chris: FWIW, it looks good how you've done it.

Comment: You could use bullet points there, @Chris, for the "Bad", "Very Bad", "Very Good", etc., and then the items underneath each bullet point would also be indented. That would probably look better than horizontal rules. I'd apply the edit so you can see how it looks, but I don't want to force my formatting approaches down your throat. If you try it, remember that code blocks under a bullet item must be intended *8* spaces, rather than the usual 4.